# A value in a form_for field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to set a value for a form field like this:

```
<%= form_for (@change_office_address), remote: true, format: :json, html: { class: :contact_form } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :city_id, class: 'form-control', value: @office.city.id, disabled: true %> 
  <%= f.submit, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

In a view I can see the id in a field, but when I tried to submit the form, I see that validation doesn't pass. The validation looks like this:

```
class ChangeOfficeAddress < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  validates :city_id, presence: true
end
```

In my schema the column `city_id` is set to `integer`. I also tried to change `f.text_field` to `f.number_field`, but it didn't help either. So, what can be wrong? Thanks ahead.

Comment: The values in the disabled field won't be submitted. Better to use some hidden fields to keep the city id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `readonly: true` instead of `disabled`. Because of `disabled` won't pass your data to server.

```
<%= f.text_field :city_id, class: 'form-control', value: @office.city.id, readonly: true %>
```